# What is the correct approach towards Factory Pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have been reading a lot of stuff regarding Factory Pattern approach and in all of them there seems to be a static method in the factory which based on switch-case returns the desired product at run-time, but this seems to violate Open Close principle as every time there is a new product the factory class needs to be modified to make necessary changes.

Below is a code i think also is in line with factory pattern but i am not sure if this approach is correct. basically what i think is that the client will know what type of factory it needs, based on that it case get the product that factory alone handles,

Please let me know if this is the right approach, or if there is a better one.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "memory"
using namespace std;

class AbstractDog{
    public:
        virtual void bark(void) = 0;
        AbstractDog(){cout << "AbstractDog created"<<'\n';}
        virtual ~AbstractDog(){cout << "AbstractDog destroyed"<<'\n';}
};

class chiwawa : public AbstractDog{
    public:
        void bark(void){
            cout << "bark like chiwawa"<<'\n';
        }
        chiwawa(){cout << "chiwawa created"<<'\n';}
        virtual ~chiwawa(){cout << "chiwawa destroyed"<<'\n';}
};

class alsatian : public AbstractDog{
    public:
        void bark(void){
            cout << "bark like alsatian"<<'\n';
        }
        alsatian(){cout << "alsatian created"<<'\n';}
        virtual ~alsatian(){cout << "alsatian destroyed"<<'\n';}
};


class AbstractDogFactory{
    public:
        virtual AbstractDog* getDog(void) = 0;
        AbstractDogFactory(){cout << "AbstractDogFactory created"<<'\n';}
        virtual ~AbstractDogFactory(){cout << "AbstractDogFactory destroyed"<<'\n';}
};

class smallDogFactory : public AbstractDogFactory{
    public:
        virtual AbstractDog* getDog(void){
            return new chiwawa;
        }
        smallDogFactory(){cout << "smallDogFactory created"<<'\n';}
        virtual ~smallDogFactory(){cout << "smallDogFactory destroyed"<<'\n';}
};

class bigDogFactory : public AbstractDogFactory{
    public:
        virtual AbstractDog* getDog(void){
            return new alsatian;
        }
        bigDogFactory(){cout << "bigDogFactory created"<<'\n';}
        virtual ~bigDogFactory(){cout << "bigDogFactory destroyed"<<'\n';}
};


int main() {
    auto_ptr<AbstractDogFactory> m_ptr_fact(new bigDogFactory);
    auto_ptr<AbstractDog>        m_ptr_dog(m_ptr_fact->getDog());
    m_ptr_dog->bark();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, sure, you can have a factory type for each target type, but that doesn't address the problem. It just adds a layer of indirection. What about your third dog type?

Comment: thats exactly my point for the static factory method when i have a third dog i will have to write a new case statement , which violates Open Close principle.

Comment: My apologies: I misread your question. Yes, the factory has to be modified when new types are added. And, yes, that may well violate some **guideline**.

Comment: :) you misread my question and down-voted it too :(

Comment: I think, better learn about factory pattern with java or some other language, there you have reflection or some way to inform factory class about existence of new derived class like static constructor from java.

Comment: No, I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @SemyonBurov - it's straightforward to implement self-registering types in C++. Whether it's a good idea is a separate question. "Java does it" is not a sound design principle.

Comment: There is really no path around updating the Factory when new selections are available.  When you add a 4th type of dog, you will need to update *something* to create an instance of the additional type.  In order to accomplish this, something must be updated in the Factory.

Answer (score 0):

One method to reduce *code* updates to a Factory is to use a lookup table with function pointers (a `std::map` will suffice too).

The code will search the table for the key, then execute (deference) a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a created instance.

When adding a new type of dog, you would update the data table.  However, you will need to write a function to return a pointer to the dog instance; thus the factory is modified.  However, the fundamental searching function (of the lookup table) doesn't need to change.

**Edit 1:**
An example:

```
typedef (Abstract_Dog *) (*Dog_Creator_Func_Pointer)();
struct Table_Entry
{
  const char *  dog_name;
  Dog_Creator_Func_Pointer p_creator;
};
// Forward references
Abstract_Dog * Create_Greyhound();
Abstract_Dog * Create_Bulldog();
//...
static const Table_Entry creators[] =
{
  {"greyhound", Create_Greyhound},
  {"bulldog",   Create_Bulldog},
  //...
};
static const unsigned int creator_quantity =
  sizeof(creators) / sizeof(creators[0]);

//...
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < creator_quantity; ++i)
{
  if (dog_name == creators[i].dog_name)
  {
    return (*creators[i].p_creator)();
  }
}
return nulptr;
```

Comment: your if (dog_name == creators[i].dog_name) does the job of switch case which i was telling, now to add a third dog you need to modify your table, thats kinda feels wrong as per open close principle.

Comment: How does one update the table without violating the open close principle?  You may taking the principle too seriously.